# How to turn off vlcpulse audio from python program?

Tags: python-3.x, vlc, pulseaudio

I'm using vlc-python bindings to play an RTSP stream on Raspberry pi3. How do I turn off vlcpulse? I don't need audio for now.

```
>>> player.audio_set_volume(0)
0
This reduced the error messages from 2 to 1 but 
>>> player = vlc.MediaPlayer("rtsp://192.168.77.114/unicast")
[015212f0] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused

>>> player = vlc.MediaPlayer("rtsp://192.168.77.114/unicast")
[015212f0] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
>>>
```

Expected result: rtsp stream playing without audio and any error
Actual result: PulseAudio is complaining

Answer (score 0):

As usual there are a number of options.

1. Turn on pulseaudio, then it won't complain.
2. When you create the `vlc.Instance()` pass it some options.

Relevant to your problem you could use:

```
opt = "--quiet"
```

This just tells vlc not to echo errors to the console (my personal preference)

or

```
opt = "--aout=adummy"
```

This tells vlc to send audio to a dummy entry rather than alsa or pulseaudio

Basically `opt` can mimic the vlc command line then simply create the vlc.Instance() like this:

```
vlc.Instance(opt)
```